# javascript use variable from function to function

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a variable matching_id initialised in a function like this:

```
function req_m () {
  var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  console.log("Matching Rule cree avec succes");

  matching_id = json[Object.keys(json)[Object.keys(json).length -1]].id;     
  console.log(matching_id);
  var matching_name = json[Object.keys(json)[Object.keys(json).length - 1]].name;
}
```

When i try to access to matching_id here:

```
if (validation()) {
  matching_rule(sensor, nameE, cond, newVal);
  firing_rule(firingType, matching_id, nameE);
  console.log(matching_id);

  document.getElementById("form1").submit(); //form submission
  alert("Matching_id: "+matching_id[0]+"\nSensor: "+sensor +"\nConditions: "+cond + " \nDevice: "+ dev +"\nNew val: "+newVal+"\n Selected: "+ firingType + "\n Name : " + nameE + " \n Email : " + email + " \n Form Id : " + formID + "\n\n Form Submitted Successfully......");
}
```

NB: The req_m function is called by the matching_rule function.
I got **undefined**. I can't access to its value.

EDIT:
Here is the matching_rule function that calling the req_m function.

```
function matching_rule(type,name,cond,val){
    var req = '{"dataPredicate":{"'+cond+'": [ {"var": "value.'+type+'"},'+val+']  },"enabled": true,"name": "'+name+'"}';
    req_match.open('POST', url_matching, true);
    req_match.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    req_match.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    req_match.setRequestHeader('X-API-KEY', kAPI);
    req_match.onreadystatechange = function(){
      console.log(req_match.status);
      if (req_match.status >= 200 && req_match.status < 400) {
        console.log(req_match);
        request_m.onload = req_m; // it's called here
        request_m.open('GET', url_matching, true);
        request_m.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json')
        request_m.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
        request_m.setRequestHeader('X-API-KEY', kAPI)
        request_m.send();
      }else {
        console.log("NOOOOOO MATCHING RULE");
      }
    }
    console.log(req);
    req_match.send(req);
 }
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: functions should `return` their results and not rely on global variables, even less so implied global variables. What you have is unmaintainable code.

Comment: return the `matching_id` variable, maybe call `req_m ()`. Something like `let matching_id = req_m();`

Comment: You would put `var matching_id` at a higher level scope. Something like `XMLHttpRequestInstance.onreadystatechange = function(){ if(XMLHttpRequestInstance.readyState === 4 && XMLHttpRequestInstance.status === 200){ var matching_id; /* req_m must be called here */ }`. I'm pointing out that this may also be an Asynchronous issue. Not enough code was supplied.

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez yeah, i edited the post. The req_m is called by the matching_rule function.

Comment: In provided code I don't see you are calling `req_m` function anywhere.

Comment: @PHPglue i declared the var at a higher level. req_must is called in the matching_rule function like i edited the post

Comment: Just as a side note, you may want to cache the result of `Object.keys(json)` so you don't call it twice... more efficient that way.

Comment: We can't see where you have that `if` condition. How can we determine where your Asynchronous and/or scope issue is?

Comment: @PHPglue the if condition is below of the req_m function and matching_rule function

Comment: Asynchronous issue. `if` condition is outside of `onreadystatechange` scope. If the data takes longer to get, `onreadystatechange`, than the `if` condition below it, then you'll have a problem.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Comment: `matching_id` is only the value you want it to be `onreadystatechange`. The if condition may *(or may not)* run first. Think of `onreadystatechange` like a click Event, as far as variable value availability. The Event has to happen before the value is what you want.